# How to install a logstash-forwarder package on Mac

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

I have installed a `logstash server` on CentOs machine. I want to install a logstash-forwarder on my `Mac`. I downloaded the `logstash-forwarderv0.4.0` but some textED file got downloaded. How can I configure 'logstash-forwarder' on my Mac ?